# How to search a artifact without groupid in maven repo using aether

Tags: maven, aether

The issue is like I have two maven remote repository. Repo A and Repo B. My task is to find out all the artifact that is available in Repo A but not in repo B. The artifact may have different groupid in the two repositories.
I am using Aether. Is there any option to find the repo B with artifactid and version id only? Thanks in advance